# Sending request from https://example.com to http://127.0.0.1:8766/test/ in Safari

Tags: javascript, security, browser, safari

First of all the request doesn't work only for Safari, but it works for Chrome and FF.

Client code is super simple here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="resp"></div>

    <a href="javascript:send_to_desktop()">Send Test</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function send_to_desktop() {
            fetch('http://localhost:8766/inc-link/', {
                mode: 'cors'
            }).then(data => data.text()).then(data=>document.getElementById('resp').innerText = data)
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Console log for Safari:

[image: safari console log]

The network tab for dev-tools is empty and server-side I don't see any request.

As I say, for chrome and for FF it works fine and this is response headers from server:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
    true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
    https://example.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers
    
Content-Length
    2
Content-Type
    text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date
    Wed, 30 Sep 2020 08:25:00 GMT
Server
    Python/3.6 aiohttp/3.6.2
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: CORS is an issue overlooked in these cases, even when an explicit flag has been set to allow CORS. It could be that if you can see more information on the Safari error. Another issue I see is you're requestion an HTTP resource from an HTTPS origin. This usually raises fetch resources issues.

Comment: @Mike it doesn't work only for safari. You can't generate ssl cert for 127.0.0.1 that will be trusted by safari. CORS headers have been provided, but the request hasn't been made.

Comment: You certainly can start a HTTPS server on your localhost. Unfortunately, not all browsers work the same. The reason as to why it wont work in Safari may be found in their forums or resources.